# Performance issue: "java.text.MessageFormat.format" vs "StringBuilder"

Tags: java, performance-testing

I want to know in compare of `MessageFormat` or `StringBuilder` class.
Let say an example i have a String. For performance wise which one is fast among:
`java.text.MessageFormat.format` or  `StringBuilder("Test ").append("Hello ")`?

```
String txt = java.text.MessageFormat.format("Test {0}"," Hello") 
String txt1=   new StringBuilder("Test ").append("Hello ")
```

I just want to know which one is use in case of best practice or performance wise

Comment: Why do you speed test it not yourself? My guess: `StringBuilder` is faster.

Comment: StringBuilder is fastest, but probably irrelevant. Simply a toString can be much more costly.

Comment: Have you tried yourself? #OneOfTheMostCommonCommentsInSO

Comment: I would be astonished if you could measure the difference in any practical application. Network and disk speeds will predominate.

Comment: MessageFormat is much more readable. Concatenating strings with StringBuilder is error prone, less readable.

Answer (score 16):

Try it yourself:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
String txt = MessageFormat.format("Test {0}"," Hello");
System.out.println("MessageFormat: " + (System.nanoTime() - start) + " ns");

start = System.nanoTime();
String txt1 = new StringBuilder("Test ").append("Hello").toString();
System.out.println("StringBuilder: " + (System.nanoTime() - start) + " ns");
```

*Output:*

> MessageFormat: 1125974 ns
>
> StringBuilder: 16705 ns

**Conclusion:**

`StringBuilder` works much faster because it just adds some chars to existing array.

Comment: Simple enough to understand.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not a good comparison, because the message format is parsed every time. Like with RegExp Pattern class, the intended use is to have the patterns/format template set up once, then used many times without reparsing it.

Comment: I measured String.format to take about 4x as long as a pre-parsed messageFormat.format()

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuilder` does only append text to a dynamic buffer, while `MessageFormat` has to parse the given format before appending the data, then `StringBuilder` is more efficient than `MessageFormat`.

Comment: Thanks ..i also think in same way StringBuilder is faster then Message.format